# How can I make my button toggle a mute and unmuted symbol as well as unmute and mute audio?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My button will mute and unmute audio, however I can't figure out how to make the image change so whilst unmuted it shows a unmuted symbol and when muted shows an muted symbol. Here's my current code:

```js
function toggleMuted() {
  var sound = document.getElementById('sound');
  sound.muted = !sound.muted;
}
```

```html
<div id="mutebut">
  <button id="soundbutton" onclick="toggleMuted()">Mute|Unmute</button>
</div>
<audio id="sound" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
  <source src="../resources/audio/junglenoise.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Comment: I don't see an image in your code to change

Comment: sorry should have made it clearer I am able to add an image but just not sure how to make it toggle when I click, so muted image when audio muted and unmuted image when audio is unmuted

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how  to follow up on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary

```js
const sound = document.getElementById('sound');

document.getElementById("soundbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.textContent = this.textContent === "Mute " ? "Unmute " : "Mute "; // change this to image.src if you have one
  sound.muted = !sound.muted;
})
```

```html
<div id="mutebut">
  <button type="button" id="soundbutton">Mute </button>
</div>
<audio id="sound" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
  <source src="../resources/audio/junglenoise.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers), [class toggling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) and [icon fonts](https://fontawesome.com/search?q=mute&o=r).

```js
const muteBtn = document.querySelector('.mute-button');

muteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  muteBtn.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(el => {
    el.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<button class="mute-button">
  <span class="hidden"><i class="fa-solid fa-volume-xmark"></i> Muted</span>
  <span><i class="fa-solid fa-volume-off"></i> Mute</span>
</button>
```